# Why a program written in the Intel assembly language cannot be executed on the PowerPC processor?

Tags: x86, powerpc

Assembly language instructions are native to the processor
used in the system. For example, a program written in the
Intel assembly language cannot be executed on the
PowerPC processor.

I am unable to understand this.please clarify me.

Comment: Consider this: A book written in French can only be read by someone who understands French. It can not be read by someone who only speaks Dutch.

Comment: Different assembly language, different instructions, entirely different architectures

Comment: There's no such thing as a cross-assembler? Um.. of course there is.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan - yes, of course there are compilers and assemblers, but if you're looking at the actual hex used on one processor's architecture, verses another company's non-compatible processor, then the actual code for a function could be different.  Hence you can't write code directly to a file and expect it to mean exactly the same to another - non family processor line.  That's why we call them "instruction sets"  x86, mmx, mmx2, etc.. are commonly known ones for "intel" processors,

Comment: I know all that. The question is not about the "actual hex used on one processor's architecture". The question is about "a program written in the Intel assembly language". For that matter, a program written in Intel assembly language won't run on Intel processors either. It has to be assembled. And there ARE cross-assemblers. It's entirely possible to generate PowerPC machine code from Intel assembly language (although some specific details, like Intel's implementation of segmenting, would not map directly from one to the other). A "best answer" really should make this distinction clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the architecture (the physical makeup determined by the logical principles of the processor) are different.

x86 and PowerPC are both accomplishing the same thing: a general purpose central processing unit to handle code in a computation device, but they are built using different ideas of how such a system works, and therefore use different forms and methods to accomplish their similar ends.

Comment: I wouldn't say architecture because its too vague, the *specific instruction set* that a processor was designed to run, in the manner, order, and for the expected outcome, was designed differently for each processor family or type. Everyone can agree that "multiplying" as a math function should be the same result across every given way to perform the act.  However, the Intel Processor does it differently than the PowerPC processor does, and while simply stating a function name, it doesn't mean the same underlying hex code is the same from one processor brand, type or family to another.

Comment: The instruction set and the architecture are two sides of the same coin, and I think it would be best to say that they are both the reason. Each one informs the other and they are both determined by the assumptions and knowledge and strengths and weaknesses of the people and teams who designed these two similar but different processors in the first place.

Comment: -"The instruction set and the architecture are two sides of the same coin"-not always true. look at processor brands Intel & AMD. They have a long running spat, *both* implement an x86 instruction set, but the architecture of the Processor are vastly different.  Even when AMD added MMX and other extensions, they didn't have to use the same Intel processor reference architecture, just so long as the AMD chip could have the same outcome from an instruction set that Intel originally created.